# H5PY: Broadcasting not supported when writing to a complex selection

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py, array-broadcasting

`h5py` gives `Broadcasting is not supported for complex selections` error when I want to write a block of data to a sub-selection of its indices, e.g. `arr[:,subarray,...] = block`. The shape of the two sides are exactly the same and I doubt why `h5py` complains about **`broadcasting`** in the first place. So, what is the source of this issue and how can I resolve that?

Please note that **reading** from `arr[:,subarray,...]` would be OK, e.g. `print(arr[:,subarray,...])` gives no errors.

```py
try:
    import h5py
    import numpy as np
    f = h5py.File('test.hdf5','w')
    arr = f.create_dataset('data', (5,1000,2), dtype=np.uint8)
    block = np.random.randint(255, size=(5,3,2))
    print(">> Shape of arr selection:", arr[:,[0,2,4],...].shape)
    print(">> Shape of random block:", block.shape)
    arr[:,[0,2,4],...] = block
finally:
    f.close()
```

The output:

```sh
>> Shape of arr selection: (5, 3, 2)
>> Shape of random block: (5, 3, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0e6663b2afa7> in <module>
      7     print(">> Shape of arr selection:", arr[:,[0,2,4],...].shape)
      8     print(">> Shape of random block:", block.shape)
----> 9     arr[:,[0,2,4],...] = block
     10 finally:
     11     f.close()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in __setitem__(self, args, val)
    882 
    883         # Perform the write, with broadcasting
--> 884         mspace = h5s.create_simple(selection.expand_shape(mshape))
    885         for fspace in selection.broadcast(mshape):
    886             self.id.write(mspace, fspace, val, mtype, dxpl=self._dxpl)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/selections.py in expand_shape(self, source_shape)
    336     def expand_shape(self, source_shape):
    337         if not source_shape == self.array_shape:
--> 338             raise TypeError("Broadcasting is not supported for complex selections")
    339         return source_shape
    340 

TypeError: Broadcasting is not supported for complex selections
```

**Versions**:

```py
>>> print(h5py.version.info)
```

```sh
Summary of the h5py configuration
---------------------------------

h5py    2.10.0
HDF5    1.12.0
Python  3.7.7 (default, May  7 2020, 21:25:33) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
sys.platform    linux
sys.maxsize     9223372036854775807
numpy   1.18.5
```

Comment: except for `HDF5 1.10.4` and `numpy 1.17.5` I have the same configuration and it does not throw me an error

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Dorian, so `HDF5 1.12` might be the culprit. I have compiled HDF5 1.12 from source. I will file an issue then ...

Comment: I reported it on https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1593 and it is now fixed by https://github.com/h5py/h5py/pull/1595.